# Engine oil in coolant

Tags: engine, ford

There's is oil appearing in the engine coolant,  does this mean i have to buy a  new engine? The car is a 2003 Ford Focus with 180k miles.

Comment: 180 miles? Or maybe 180000 miles?

Comment: Theres is oil appearing into the engine coolant , does this mean i have to buy a new engine? 180000miles

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the cause of the fluids mixing: buying a new engine would be the most extreme of the possible repairs. The simplest repair for this would likely be a gasket replacement, which may still be quite costly, since (for example) head gaskets require taking apart most of the engine to replace.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't necessarily mean you need to buy a new engine. Although if you don't get it seen to, you will be in the market for one soon enough.

Generally speaking, as @user3188168 said, it's quite likely that it's the head gasket that's split, allowing some oil into the cooling system. The head gasket will need changing, and your radiator will need a flush out as well as the rest of the coolant galleries in the engine.

In a more severe scenario, your head itself may be split (I have seen a few duratech 2.0's do this). In that case, you'll need a new head. More expensive for sure, but still repairable.

But basically, a new engine is only needed in the event of catastrophic failures.